# Xamarin forms app opened from a custom URI scheme crashes when there is no instance of app running

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to open a Xamarin forms app from a URI link sent to an email. I have registered a URI scheme in "AndroidManifest.xml" that goes to OpenFromURIActivity.cs and then it starts MainActivity. The code works fine only when an instance of the app is already open and running otherwise it won't work and crashes in mainactivity. Here is my code in MainActivity.cs. I check if the "intent.data" (URI data) is null then I continue to load the app.cs otherwise I have another app class called "AppOpenURI" which I load that one. My doubt is that it crashes because the bundle is null in mainactivity?! Please advise.

[image]

```
public class OpenFromURIActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                var mainActivityIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
                mainActivityIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                mainActivityIntent.SetData(Intent.Data);
                StartActivity(mainActivityIntent);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var properties = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                { "OnCreate", "OpenFromURIActivity" }
                };
                Crashes.TrackError(ex, properties);
            }
        }      
    }

public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init(enableFastRenderer: false);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            if (Intent.Data == null)
            {
                LoadApplication(new App(new AndroidInitializer()));
            }
            else
            {
                var appFromUri = new AppOpenURI(Intent.Data.EncodedAuthority);
                LoadApplication(appFromUri);
            }    
        }
```

Comment: What error did it throw when it crash ?

Comment: MobileApp.Droid.OpenFromURIActivity.onCreate
OpenFromURIActivity.java, line 29
Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0300b8 a=-1}

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0300b8 a=-1}

Comment: Could you share a sample project if possible.

Comment: I will create one and share it with you. Of course, if it happens in the sample project!

Comment: Ok,i will test it after you share the sample.